# Webcrawler not working with HTTPS

Tags: http, python-3.x, https, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am having an issue with my web crawler. It can run through any regular old website like a charm, but when it runs into a https protocol it doesn't seem to work.

This is the error I am getting when I try to run a https url through my crawler (name 'htmltext' is not defined)

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
re.IGNORECASE = True
from urllib.parse import urlparse

#SourceUrl
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"

urls = [url]

z = urlparse(urls[0])

TopLevel = z.scheme+'://'+z.netloc

visited =[url]

robotsUrl = TopLevel +'/robots.txt'



while len(urls) < 100:
        try:
            htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
            robots = urllib.request.urlopen(robotsUrl).read()
            disallowList = re.findall(b'Disallow\:\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\*\-\/\_\?\.\%\:\&]+)', robots)
        except:
            print (urls[0])
        sourceCode = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, "html.parser")
        urls.pop(0)
        print(len(urls))
        for link in sourceCode.findAll('a', href=True):
            if "http://" not in link['href']:
                link['href'] = urllib.parse.urljoin(url,link['href'])
            in_disallow = False
            for i in range(len(disallowList)):
                if (disallowList[i]).upper().decode() in link['href'].upper():
                    in_disallow = True
                    break
            if not in_disallow:
                if link['href'] not in visited:
                        urls.append(link['href'])
                        visited.append(link['href'])
print (visited)
```

Comment: The above code is working fine at my machine, except for the while loop. The `print(urls[0])` inside the while loop should be replaced by `break`

Comment: What are you running it with, I am using Visual Studio.

Comment: I am using PyCharm, but if you face any such confusion then try to run it from console.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, it works on google and yahoo just fine even though they have https as protocol but it won't work on youtube or wikipedia...

Comment: But the wikipedia one is working for me.

Comment: Running out of pycharm and I get this: C:\Python34\python.exe "C:/Users/dakot/PycharmProjects/untitled/Web Crawler"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dakot/PycharmProjects/untitled/Web Crawler", line 31, in <module>
    sourceCode = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, "html.parser")
NameError: name 'htmltext' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: The code works fine at my place, except that the while loop is wrong.